# Visual Studio 2008 (2010 Ultimate Edition) cannot open a project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

A couple of us here in the office installed Visual Studio 2010 which after full installation we saw included visual studio 2008. 
Now when we attempt to open 2008 projects in this edition of 2008  it fails with a long message about not supporting the project extension of .csproj.

A bit more checking into it I see that there are no csharp or visual basic extensions installed for this edition of visual studio but mainly sql extensions.

Can someone confirm if this edition of visual studio 2008 can be used for regular application (console, web, windows) development (if so how?) or if its only suited for sql development?

**------------------- Visual Studio 2008 (incl with 2010 Ultimate) About Info -->**

Microsoft Visual Studio 2008
Version 9.0.30729.1 SP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 3.5 SP1

Installed Edition: IDE Standard

*-- several host fixes removed from list.*

SQL Server Analysis Services
Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services Designer 
Version 10.0.5500.0

SQL Server Integration Services
Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer
Version 10.0.5500.0 ((Katmai_PCU_Main).110921-2358 )

SQL Server Reporting Services
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Designers 
Version 10.0.5500.0

Comment: VS2010 Ultimate does *not* include VS2008.  Post the *exact* text of the message.

Comment: ... And/or post the exact product that you installed.  If you open the About window in VS it'll tell you what components are installed.  For example, it may be that you've installed the TFS2008 client, which runs in the VS2008 IDE (and isn't necessary for accessing TFS2008 from VS2010).

Comment: Thanks guys. Yes, I checked the installed components (incl above). As you can see its just sql stuff.

Answer (score 2):

`VS 2010` and `VS 2008` UE include all regular applications. VS2010 also installed 2008 folder `Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0.`. Just simply use 2010 and you'll be fine. It supports all versions.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Unfortunately touching a VS2008 project with VS2010 will result in the solution being updated. I personally have no problem with this, but many developers I work with do.